# Make choice from combo box enable different combo box

Tags: visual-studio, combobox

I am new to this website, so I apologize if this question was asked and I could not find it.

I am trying to create a program using Visual Studio 2010 where if you select a word from either list A or B, (where lists and B are combo boxes), then it gets defined on the bottom of the screen.

The problem I am having is making a selection from a combo box with the choices for lists A and B enable/disable the appropriate list.

To phrase that better, I have a 3 combo box lists, one with choices "English and Hebrew", one titled cboEnglish, and one titled cboHebrew.

How do I make it so that if I select "English", then cboEnglish is enabled, and if I select "Hebrew", then THAT list is enabled?

I threw a bit of coding around, but all it accomplishes is that no matter what choice I pick, then the English gets enabled every time:

```
Private Sub English()
    cboHebrew.Enabled = False
    cboEnglish.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Hebrew()
    cboEnglish.Enabled = False
    cboHebrew.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

I had a draft where the choices English and Hebrew were buttons, which would make the coding really easy to do (The above code was copied from that version), but I did not really like how it looked.

I am fairly new to Visual Studio (like 1 1/2 months of use), so I apologize if this is a dumb question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I ended up turning the main combo box into an integer, and defining each of the sub options to make the other boxes true/false using the same procedure as if I would have just been using 2 buttons to enable/disable them. 
Not sure if this procedure is ideal, but hey, it works (for now)

```
Dim intLanguage As Integer
    intLanguage = Me.cboLanguage.SelectedIndex
    Select Case intLanguage
        Case 0
            English()
        Case 1
            Hebrew()
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub English()
    'This attempts to enable English list
    cboEnglish.Enabled = True
    cboHebrew.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Hebrew()
    'This attempts to enable English list
    cboEnglish.Enabled = False
    cboHebrew.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not into Visual Basic, but basically you should place your code into handler method. In your case it should SelectedIndexCHanged (see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_combobox.htm).

Answer (score 0):

A simple if then else statement should work.

```
    If combobox.optionA = selected Then
               comboxBox.optionB = false
    Else comobox.optionB = selected then
    comboxBox.optionA = false
END if
```

Comment: I tried it using specifics for the options, but I was getting error issues. Want me to list them all out? Also how would I code out using the if statement for combo box 1 to enable/disable combo boxes 2 & 3?

Comment: Hi sorry I couldn't respond earlier. Your approach below looks good.